# Asp.net how to Hide standard html and display based off of runat server

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I need to hide  some instructions and display them based of of code in the C# codebehind.  with the runat="server"

Here is what I have right now

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" Visible="false"></asp:TextBox>
```

In the c# I have

```
if (Title == "Beer")
            {
                TextBox4.Visible = true;
                TextBox4.Text = "Instructions go here";
            }
```

Is what I would like to do is use a html paragraph tag for the instructions and only have the TextBox and Labels for the data.  What can I do accomplish this?  What Class can I use to hide a paragraph tag and only display it if it meets criteria in the if loop.

Also is the there a way to have the if loop say

```
if (Title == "Beer" OR Title == "Wine")
```

Or do I need to do a series of if loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for a `PlaceHolder` or a `Panel`.

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server" Visible="false">
    <p>
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
        <br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" Visible="false"></asp:TextBox>
    </p>
</asp:PlaceHolder>
```

And then in code behind (the double `||` is the `OR` equivalent)

```
if (Title == "Beer" || Title == "Wine")
{ 
    PlaceHolder1.Visible = true;
    TextBox4.Text = "Instructions go here";
}
```

> A `panel` will wrap everything inside a `<div>`, a `PlaceHolder` does
>   not. [Read more](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.placeholder(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @ VDWWD Thanks for your help.  I will try the Placeholder or Panel.  Since I am fairly new to ASP.net where do I find a good reference to figure out what class I can use and which ones are the most commonly use classes?

Answer (score 0):

In your c#, you can hide the textbox/label when using TextBox4.visible = false;

Example:

```
`if (Title == "Beer"|| Title == "Wine")
        {
            TextBox4.Visible = true;
            TextBox4.Text = "Instructions go here";
        }
else        {
            TextBox4.Visible = false;
        }`
```

Comment: Is there anyway not to use a textbox and use paragraph tags or something else for the Instructions  but still keep the hidden like you can on a textbox?

Comment: When I use a textbox my instructions are way longer than the textbox and the textbox is editable.

Comment: You can include it inside a asp:panel giving it an id then referencing it in the c# to hide the contents